# Can you only get some attributes of a collection in a well with spring data?

Tags: mongodb, jpa, spring-data

I have a collection in mongo with the attributes: attr1, attr2, ..., attrN. Can I get only some attributes from the collection in a well so that the java class does not have the n attributes? That is, the well would have only, for example, attr1 and attr2 and attr3.

from the following document:

```
{
    attr1: value1,
    attr2: value2,
    attr4: value3,
    attr3: value4,
    //...
    attrN: valueN
}
```

I only want this:

```
class Entity{
    String attr1;
    String attr2;
    String attr3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think you will use some tool to deserialize your MongoDB record to your Java object. Look into `com.fasterxml.jackson` from https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson. Then, you can annotate your Java class with `JsonIgnoreProperties` and list the properties you want to ignore:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"attr4", "attrN"})
class Entity{
    String attr1;
    String attr2;
    String attr3;
}
```